# Reading Multiple Lines, ArrayList

Tags: java

The problem I wanted to solve is:

Sereja has an array a, consisting of n integers a1, a2, ..., an. The boy cannot sit and do nothing, he decided to study an array. Sereja took a piece of paper and wrote out m integers l1, l2, ..., lm (1 ≤ li ≤ n). For each number li he wants to know how many distinct numbers are staying on the positions li, li + 1, ..., n. Formally, he want to find the number of distinct numbers among ali, ali + 1, ..., an.?

Sereja wrote out the necessary array elements but the array was so large and the boy was so pressed for time. Help him, find the answer for the described question for each li.

I need to be able to read an input like such:

```
10 10
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 100000 99999
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I tried using buffered reader, but I always get a runtime error

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
      int n = scan.nextInt();
      int m = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
      int[] a = new int[n];
      int[] l = new int[m];
      for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
      {
         a[i] = scan.nextInt();
      }
      a[n] = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
      for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
      {
         l[j] = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
      }
      int counter = 0;
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
      {
         for(int x=l[k]; x<= n; x++)
         {
            if(!(list.contains(x)))
            {
                list.add(x);
                counter++;
            }
         }
         System.out.println(counter);
      }
   }
}
```

Whenever I run this program, I get a runtime error. The output that I need to get with the aforementioned input is 
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1

Why isn't it working?

---

OK, I tried this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String[] tokens = br.readLine().split(" ");
     int n = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
     int m = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
     String[] tokenstwo = br.readLine().split(" ");
     int[] a = new int[n];
     int[] l = new int[m];
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
         a[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenstwo[i]);
      }
      for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
      {
         l[j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      }
      int counter = 0;
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
      {
         for(int x=l[k]; x<= n; x++)
         {
            if(!(list.contains(x)))
            {
                list.add(x);
                counter++;
            }
         }
         System.out.println(counter);
      }
   }
}
```

It said something about IOException. Therefore, i added the throws ioexception at the top. It still give a runtime error though.

Comment: I dont' see you have used `BufferedReader`. You are using `scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code for taking the input. Fit it for your need.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] tokens = br.readLine().split(" ");
int n1 = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
```